# AsyncTask throbber shows on previous tab of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm making an app with 4 tabs, the third one is `ListView` with data parsed from `xml` by `AsyncTask`.
I've got a problem with throbber (circle progress bar) which shows on a previous tab and I can't find solution of it.
Does anybody knows how to prevent this kind of pre-loading when `AsyncTask` starts on previous tab, not on `ListView` (third) tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent pre-loading fragments in ViewPager.
But you can use some external libraries to take that result.
For example, [ViewPagerExtensions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) or [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator).